# Map a rails collection by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have an employee model and a sales model, an employee has_many sales. I want to pull the weekly sales for each employee, 
so far I can get a collection of all the sales for the current week for each employee;

```
def weekly_sales
    self.sales.where(created_at: (Date.today.beginning_of_week..(Date.today.beginning_of_week + 5)))
end
```

which gives;

```
<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Sale id: 1054, amount: 2668, new_sale: true, created_at: "2015-07-21 00:00:00", updated_at: "2015-07-21 11:48:03", employee_id: 17>, #<Sale id: 1053, amount: 7128, new_sale: false, created_at: "2015-07-21 00:00:00", updated_at: "2015-07-21 11:48:03", employee_id: 17>, #<Sale id: 1052, amount: 4781, new_sale: true, created_at: "2015-07-20 00:00:00", updated_at: "2015-07-21 11:48:03", employee_id: 17>, #<Sale id: 1051, amount: 4491, new_sale: true, created_at: "2015-07-20 00:00:00", updated_at: "2015-07-21 11:48:03", employee_id: 17>]>
```

I want to end up with an array that has 5 elements, each is the sale.amount total for each day monday to friday but I'm not sure how to correctly build it.
Runninng weekly sales on a tuesday would give a 5 element array e.g [ 350,290,0,0,0]

Comment: G::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function sum(timestamp without time zone) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT SUM(sales.created_at) FROM "sales" WHERE "sales"."emp...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT SUM(sales.created_at) FROM "sales" WHERE "sales"."employee_id" = $1 AND ("sales"."created_at" BETWEEN '2015-07-20' AND '2015-07-25')
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function sum(timestamp without time zone) does not exist

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a hash, with dates as keys, and values, which are the sum of sales for this date (and it only makes one query to the db):

```
def weekly_sales
  sales.group("DATE(created_at)").count
end
```

To get the sum of all sales, grouped by date:

```
def weekly_sales
  sales.group("DATE(created_at)").sum(:amount)
end
```

Comment: this only counts the number of records not the value

Comment: Sorry, missed that, while reading the question. I fixed the answer

Answer (score 0):

i hope this one will give you your desired output

```
def weekly_sales
  self.sales.where(created_at: (Date.today.beginning_of_week..(Date.today.beginning_of_week + 5))).group("DATE(sales.created_at)").sum("sales.amount")
end
```